# Can the product of Grails framework be class as Java-based web application?

Tags: java, grails, web-applications, groovy, frameworks

When I search for Java frameworks, one of the popular result is Grails. However, from what I can understand it uses Groovy as the language which is similar to Java. Does this similarity grant me to call the use of Grails as Java-based web application?

Comment: grails is your groovy language based MVC framework , with spring and hibernate functionality , its almost a java framework , now if you can clearly ask what exactly do you want to ask , well if you want this to communicate with a java project , it surely can

Comment: It's a JVM based web application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not about Groovy being similar to Java, but Groovy being a language that compiles to the  JVM. So from a JVM perspective, it does not matter if it is Java or Groovy, they both generate .class files. Because of  that, Groovy programming can make use of all java libraries , so Grails takes advantage of this to be based on Hibernate, Spring and other Java frameworks. So for me, the answer is Yes, you can say Grails is a Java based web application.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking this because your hosting company says that it can host Java based web applications, then I think it's fair to say that your Grails app is a java based web application.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:
"Grails is an open source web application framework that uses the Groovy programming language (which is in turn based on the Java platform)". I believe this grants you to call it a java based web application, or better yet, as answered above, a JVM based web application. It is good to realize that due to this you can use existing java libraries with grails, and also whenever necessary [use java source code for your development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094976/can-i-grails-project-have-java-code-in-it-or-you-have-to-import).